# How to make a custom button display a menu

Tags: wpf, button, drop-down-menu

I have a custom button in WPF that I want to use as my main menu button for style reasons. I am trying to create a menu similar to that of [Microsoft Office 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/what-happened-to-the-file-menu-HA010120473.aspx). I've added menu items to the button, but a menu does not open when I click on the button. In fact, I get a compiler error that says that `Content` has been set too many times. I think this may have to do with my image. What other code do I need to add or change in my button to make it actually open the menu when clicked, error free?

This is what I have under my button right now:

```
<!--- MAIN MENU BUTTON -->
        <Button Width="50"
        Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!--- MAIN MENU BUTTON IMAGE -->
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image
                        Source="..." 
                               Width="40"
                               Height="40" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
            <!-- MENU COMMAND -->
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem x:Name="MainMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="New" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="Exit_Click" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
         </Button>
```

I've read examples that talk about binding, but I am not really sure how to do that in this specific instance.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a MenuItem?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I know how to use these. I would like my button to act as a menuItem.

EDIT: I see what you mean. I have changed my code to `MenuItem` from `ContextMenu`. The only problems I'm having now are compiler errors because apparently `MenuItem` does not work well with `<Button.ContextMenu>`

Comment: I changed my code, stupid mistake.

Comment: In your case the `Menu` is out of `StackPanel`, so you get an error. In content, if contains more than one element, then they must all be in the panel (`StackPanel`, `Grid`, etc.). But why is my answer to you is not suitable?

Comment: Okay, that's a little closer. I never said it wasn't suitable. I just think it has to do with ContextMenu a little more than MenuItems. It looks like I accidentally started out trying to setup a ContextMenu.

Comment: Let me look at it for a second. I don't accept answers until it's working, sorry.

Comment: I understand that, I just thought you needed something else. In the office, opera, etc press a button and `ContextMenu` from appears. A standard `Menu` control, it is generally horizontal, and `ContextMenu` - vertical.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the *RoutedEvent* `Button.Click`, to show `ContextMenu`:

```
<Button Name="MainButton" Content="Button with ContextMenu" Width="150" Height="30">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Main">
                <MenuItem Header="Find" />
                <MenuItem Header="Add" />
                <MenuItem Header="View" />
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>

    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="MainButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainContextMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContextMenu.IsOpen)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

`Output`

[image]

**`Note:`** Add `sys` namespace like that:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

to your `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="ShowContextMenu.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" .../>
```

Comment: I get ""sys" is an undeclared namespace. XML is not valid." and "The type 'sys:Boolean' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly ref..."

Comment: Okay, the only problem is, once I open the menu and click somewhere else, the "Main" box stays open.

Comment: For me, working standard. Click outside the `ContextMenu` closes it.

Comment: For me it doesn't close and even stays open when I switch windows.

Comment: You created an *empty* project with my example, or there was something else defined?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33506/discussion-between-anatoliy-nikolaev-and-eric-after-dark)

Comment: I am prototyping with an empty window and my button. My button has a few different styles and triggers, as well as an image set in a `stackpanel`.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I'm trying to use the same exact thing, but I've an exception saying that it cannot find the MainContextMenu. I'm using a DevExpress SimpleButton instead of the button for skinning, but I don't think it's linked. Do you have any idea?